# Do followers of Advaita accept Madhvacharya's Mahabharata tatparya nirnaya commentary?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya

Do followers of Advaita accept   Mahabharata  tatparya nirnaya ?
If not did any of advaita acharyas or scholars either refuted points or whole of Mahabharata tatparya nirnaya ?

Comment: OK swiftpushkar

Comment: your question is entirely opinionated.

Comment: Actually my question is what is opinion of advaita scholars like sridhara swami ext

Comment: Agree. Pls reword the question on the lines of What is the commentary of followers of Advaita on Mahabharata's Tatparya nirnaya.